# Error detecting when runing BCP from C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, bcp

I want to run BCP from C# console application and be able to detect syntax, permissions or other errors returned by BCP into CMD. I tried ErrorDataReceived event but it seems to me that it does not fire in any case. Can you please help me with this issue, thank you

```
  processCMD("bcp", String.Format("\"select 'COUNTRY', 'MONTH' union all SELECT COUNTRY, cast(MONTH as varchar(2)) FROM DBName.dbo.TableName\" queryout {0}FILE_NAME.csv -c -t; -T -{1}", ExportDirectory, SQLServer));

    static void processCMD(string fileName, string arguments) 
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(NetErrorDataHandler);
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();

            }

            private static void NetErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs errLine)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(errLine);
                Console.ReadLine();
                // throw Exception ...
            }
```

/-- FINAL SOLUTION: ------------------------------------------------------ /

```
static void processCMD(string fileName, string arguments)
        {
            StringBuilder cmdOutput = new StringBuilder();

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();

            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                cmdOutput.Append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();

            if(!cmdOutput.ToString().Contains("successfully bulk-copied"))
                throw new BCPError(cmdOutput.ToString());
        }

        public class BCPError : Exception
        {
            public BCPError()
            {
            }

            public BCPError(string message)
                : base(message)
            {
            }

            public BCPError(string message, Exception inner)
                : base(message, inner)
            {
            }
        }
```

and if it is throwed, you can display error for example like `e.ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BCP is a command line program, you should expect the `stdout` to be the console, unless you redirect it. You could try this way:

```
        static string processCMD(string fileName, string arguments) 
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            proc.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
                output.Append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();
            return output.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: So i will parse if end of stream is equal to standard behaviour and if output will different then i can throw an error, nice.. thank you i will try it soon as possible